# Fixed orientation for Iphone in universal app

Tags: iphone, orientation

I have developed a universal app I want to support all orientation for IPAD but for Iphone I just want  UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait and UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown only for this I have

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
        return NO;
    }else{
        return YES;
    }
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{

     if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
         return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
     }else{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
     }

} 
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
     if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){

    return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown ;
     }else{
         return YES;
     }

}
```

But still is not stop the orientation in landscape

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply disable all other orientations except the `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` and `UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown` one for the **iPhone** from the **Summary** like in the description below. *In the pic the Upside down is disabled please enable it*. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For portrait upside down you have to use navigation controller

1) I created a new subclass of UINavigationController, and added shouldAutorotate and supportedInterfaceOrientation methods:

```
     // MyNavigationController.h:
     #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

     @interface MyNavigationController : UINavigationController

     @end

    // MyNavigationController.m:
     #import "MyNavigationController.h"
     @implementation MyNavigationController
     ...
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
     }

     - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
     }
    ...
       @end
```

2) In the AppDelegate, I did use my new subclass to show my root ViewController (it is introScreenViewController, a UIViewController subclass) and did set the self.window.rootViewController, so it looks that:

```
      nvc = [[MyNavigationController alloc]              initWithRootViewController:introScreenViewController];
     nvc.navigationBarHidden = YES;
      self.window.rootViewController = nvc;
      [window addSubview:nvc.view];
   [window makeKeyAndVisible];
```