# UINavigationController.view.frame returns portrait CGRect even in landscape orientation. How to fix this?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I've a UINavigationController and its started in landscape mode right from the beginning. My iPad app is made to support only Landscape interface orientations. However, whenever I call the navigationController.view.frame, the returned CGRect is for portrait.

How can I get the CGRect showing the landscape values in frame ? Like (0,0,1024,768) instead of (0,0,768,1024)

Comment: do you use ib. change the orientation of the ib and log the value

Comment: Is your navigation controller root of the window? Does this really applies also to `bounds` property? Did you try to log `interfaceOrientation` too? You may be logging it before rotation ever happens.

Comment: @iMartin : yes, I checked that. It returns the bounds correctly, but messes up with frame. I've edited the question.

Comment: Are you adding this navigationcontroller to window - by adding subview or by assigning rootViewController?

Comment: I'm adding it as window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;

Comment: check your orientation settings in info.plist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use `bounds` property instead.**

It looks like your navigation controllers is `rootViewController` of the window. The window manages autorotation by rotating its root view controller. Rotation is done by applying transfrom, so `navController.view` should print non-identity `transform` too.

- `frame` is **outer rectangle in parent coordinates** and since the coordinate system of window didn't change, the frame is the same in all orientations. It is suitable to be used by sibling or parent views.
- `bounds` is **inner rectangle**. It will have correct dimensions in your case and is suitable to use by its subviews to make calculations

Usually `frame` and `bounds` have the same dimensions only when the `transform` is `CGAffineTransformIdentity`. Once the transfrom is changing, you need to know when to use `frame` and when `bounds`. You can find many resources describing the difference between `frame` and `bounds` on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

in xcode click on the project file.In Summary details you will have orientations with four buttons each specifying a orientation.you can uncheck the unwanted orientation or check only two landscape orientations.you will get it.

Comment: Yes, in the info.plist I have kept only two landscape orientations.

Comment: not in the info plist.sometimes in xcode summary tab (which info and build settings tab) contains orientations buttons uncheck the unwanted ones.

Comment: Try this     - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Overriden to allow any orientation.
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
     
    }

Comment: I don't have orientation issue. The controller is displaying properly in landscape and working. Only that the CGRect returned from navController.view.frame sticks the result to just portrait values.

Comment: Do you have xib file? In that case you need to check the orientation as landscape in xib properties??

Comment: No, xib file for navigationController. Its only for viewControllers. And all the views in xib of viewControllers are set to Landscape.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for the status bar orientation from the start itself. This would show you the  orientation the App is in . Then you can easily block the orientation.

```
-(void)checkLaunchOrientation:(id)sender{

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    BOOL isLandscape = UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]);

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation) || isLandscape)
    {
        isPortrait = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        isPortrait = YES;
    }
}
```

Also check the link to my answer here also ... [Fixed orientation for Iphone in universal app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421300/fixed-orientation-for-iphone-in-universal-app/17421363#17421363) .. It explains have to close a particular orientation.